# Update item without modifying the expiry

Tags: java, couchbase

Is there a way to update an item in couchbase without altering its expiration time? I am using Java SDK and Couchbase 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible right now. The simple reason is that the underlying protocol does not allow for it - everytime the document is modified its expiration time is reset.

The only reasonable workaround I can think of right now can be used when your expiration times are long and a small change won't matter: when you create a view you can grab the TTL as part of the meta information. So you load the current TTL and write the new document with this TTL (maybe then even substracting the time your business processing took). This would approximate it (and it can also work with N1QL).

Comment: Great. I think the approach of getting TTL from meta look good.